# issues in downloading the pdf files using axios in reactjs (context api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Can any one please help me out on how to download the pdf files when reactjs(using context api) is used as frontend(using axios),as on server side every thing is fine , if i click on download link - following response is shown in console [Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evln9.png)

this is the client side code making req:

```
const pdfFileDownload = async (dlIdInfo) => {
    const { id } = dlIdInfo;
    console.log(`pdf file id`, id);
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `/pub/pdfdload/${id}`,
            responseType: 'blob',
            
        });
        console.log(res.data);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
    }

}
```

this is server side code:

```
router.get("/pdfdload/:id", async (req, res, next) => {

const fileId = req.params.id;

try {
    const fetchedFileToDl = await FILESDB.findById(fileId);
  
    const fileArr = fetchedFileToDl.pdfFiles;
   
    fileArr.map(filename => {
        const editedFileName = filename.split("/")[1];
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../", "public", editedFileName);
        
        const files = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' + editedFileName + '"');
        files.pipe(res);

    });
    

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually do:

```
const downloadFileAsPDF = (name, data) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data], {type: `application/pdf`}));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', name);
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
 
const pdfFileDownload = async (dlIdInfo) => {
    const { id } = dlIdInfo;
    console.log(`pdf file id`, id);
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `/pub/pdfdload/${id}`,
            responseType: 'blob',
        });

        downloadFileAsPDF('file.pdf', res.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
    }

}
```

It's really simple but it get the job done.

Comment: its working but fileArr has multiple pdf files to download, but only one pdf file is getting downloaded , when i check response in network  headers ,the content-disposition is displayed with only one filename but at server console multiple filesname are being displayed ... what might be the reason ???  how could we make multiple pdf file download ??